# Domain names for web interfaces

Tags: dns, ubuntu-10.10, subdomain

I've got a home server running Ubuntu Server 10.10 and I've got a few things installed on it like uTorrent, and a Minecraft server. Utorrent has a web UI that can be accessed at IP:8081 and the Minecraft server has one at IP:8080. Is there any way I can access these via subdomains like utorrent.example.com and minecraft.example.com?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a service like DynDns.com that would let you assign a domain name without having to run your own DNS.

Sound like a perfect fit for your needs.

Comment: Also, you can use the dynamic client provided by DynDns or whoever, or `apt-get install ddclient`.

Comment: Will that be able to resolve different ports on the same IP?